# MSVC resource file VERTGUIDE / HORZGUIDE

Tags: visual-c++

What are the meaning of HORZGUIDE and VERTGUIDE?

I could not find any documentation in msdn related to these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't documented.  This is meta-data that dialog editor generates to store the state of the editor.  You'll find this inside a DESIGNINFO block in the .rc file.

Note the rulers displayed at the top and left of the dialog.  You can click inside the ruler to add a guide that helps you align controls.  Every horizontal guide generates a HORZGUIDE line inside the block.  Same idea for vertical guides.

Also note margin values, the start and end of the ruler.

Comment: So do these values affect runtime behavior?

Comment: No, only the dialog editor uses it.  You don't see the lines at runtime.

Comment: if i add some vertical guides in the dialog box design UI, how to remove them later?